# SQL Server 2016, return json and non json together

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2016

Is there a way to return json and non json data together? For example:

```
Column1    |          Column2

1          |  {["something":"value", "column2": "value2"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use AS JSON

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'  
{  
  "Other":[{
    "something": "value", 
    "column2": "value2"}],
    "Id": 1
}'  

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON ( @json )  
WITH (   
  [Id] int '$.Id',
  [Other]  nvarchar(MAX)  AS JSON  
)
```